# Asking feedback on a new answer for an old/closed question

Tags: support

I provided an answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-is-anova-taught-used-as-if-it-is-a-different-research-methodology-compared/3548#3548) on a closed question asked on July and I would really like some feedback (I am not after reputation points!). Since it is already answered, it is unlikely to attract any people to comment. What is the best way to do this without nagging people and making a new question?

Answer (score 4):

That question is not closed. It is not possible to add answers to a question that is actually closed. See this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3473/28) as an example of a closed question.

The question you linked to has an 'accepted answer' which does not prevent other users from adding answers as you yourself did. When a new answer is added to a question or a question is edited that question is bumped to the top of the active questions which enables others to see the new answers and/or question edits.

I am sure several users have seen your answer and would have left comments if they felt that they were confused about some aspect of your answer.

Comment: You are right it is not closed. I updated my question to "old/closed". The whole issue is that I do not want to draw attention by adding a duplicate question.

Comment: Of course, adding a duplicate question is not appropriate. But, as I said in my answer, if appropriate someone will leave you feedback via the comments as the question would have been bumped up.

Comment: My issue is that the probability of drawing attention to new answers on old/closed questions is not the same as all the other answers. You might say it decreases with the age of the question. Maybe a new answer can go on top of the most popular  answer for a while, to offset its reduced probability.

Comment: @Ηλίας When a new answer is proposed, not only is the associated question bumped up on the main page ("active view" for the top questions), but the author of the latest edit is also visible by everyone.